# Freeing a node in a tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

This is a conceptual question. I want to delete a particular node from a tree, meaning that I free this particular node and set it to null. Do I need to make its parent node's child pointer also set to null since it won't have a child pointer, or will freeing the original node and setting it to free anyway set the next pointer of the parent node to null?

Comment: Freeing memory never sets any pointers.

Comment: If the deleted node is a leaf node, setting the parent pointer to it back to null is appropriate (and you must code it; the system won't do it for you).  If it is not a leaf node (it has its own children), then you need to reorganize the tree so that the sub-trees from the deleted node are still accessible.  How you do that depends on the rules for the tree.

Comment: But I am setting the freed node to NULL as well afterwards. Thats why I am thinking that the change would be reflected in its parent node as well.

Comment: No; the memory management system doesn't do your thinking for you.

Comment: Thank you. So after freeing and setting the node to-be-deleted as NULL, I set its parent's child node to null as well.

Comment: Setting variables/fields also never sets any other variables, even if they happen to have the same value. So as long as it’s the variables themselves you’re setting, you need to set all of them, yes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, unless your requirements say that deleting a non leaf node is equivalent to deleting a subtree. Just to say that it is a matter of requirements. And the question to OP becomes: what is the required behavior?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni — yes, if the 'delete node' operation means 'delete node and any subtree below it', then you have different work to do.  You'd need a depth-first (recursive) function to delete the left and right subtrees before deleting the selected node, and then you'd still need to nullify the pointer in the parent node, assuming there is one.  But 'delete node and any subtrees' is a feasible interpretation of the requirement.  As you say, more clarity — and some code — is required.  And the memory management system isn't going to rescue anything.

Comment: This question is unclear. What does this mean: "... I free this particular node and **set it to null**" What is it that you set to null? A pointer I assume - but which pointer? The pointer to a node is normally held by the parent but your text seems to talk about something else. Add your code  so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: It would be really good if you could provide an [MRE] so we can takl about the code and not about interpretations of statements formulated in a natrual language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to make its parent node's child pointer also set to null since it won't have a child pointer

Yes, this is application-level logic so it must be handled by the one implementing the tree (you).

> will freeing the original node and setting it to free anyway set the next pointer of the parent node to null?

No. Also note that calling `free` does not set the passed pointer to NULL. It is therefore good practice to do so after calling `free`.